# C - Printing negative int values as hex produces too many characters

Tags: c

Compile using gcc 4.1.2 on CentOS-5 64 bit.

Printing an integer as a two-character hex string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
   int8_t iNegVar = -1;
   int8_t iPosVar =  1;

   printf(" int negative var is <%02X>\n", iNegVar);
   printf(" int positive var is <%02X>\n", iPosVar);

   return 0;
}
```

Since the value is only 1 byte, I expect that an integer value of '-1' would print "0xFF".  However, I get:

```
 int negative var is <FFFFFFFF>
 int positive var is <01>
```

---

I tried abstracting this to a char* buffer to print 1 byte at a time.  This yielded the same results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void print_hex(void* pBuffer, uint8_t uiBufSize);
int main(void)
{
   int8_t iNegVar = -1;
   int8_t iPosVar =  1;

   printf(" int negative var is <%02X>\n", iNegVar);
   print_hex(&iNegVar, 1);                               //pass by reference 


   printf(" int positive var is <%02X>\n", iPosVar);
   print_hex(&iPosVar, 1);                               //pass by reference

   return 0;
}


void print_hex(void* pBuffer, uint8_t uiBufSize)
{
   int i;
   char pTmp[3];                                 //Holds 2-character string, plus NULL
   char* pByteBuff = pBuffer;                    //Use char* to parse byte-by-byte

   for(i = 0; i < uiBufSize; i++)                //Process all bytes in buffer
   {
      sprintf(pTmp, "%02X", pByteBuff[i]);       //store each byte as 2-character string in "pTmp"
      printf(" Converted to %s!\n\n", pTmp);
   }
}
```

Prints:

```
int negative var is <FFFFFFFF>
Converted to FFFFFFFF!

int positive var is <01>
Converted to 01!
```

---

I got thinking that "char" is implemented in C as an integer type, so I decided to try changing "char* pByteBuff" to "*unsigned* char* pByteBuff" in the "print_hex" function.  This worked, and only printed the two characters I was expecting:

```
int negative var is <FFFFFFFF>
Converted to FF!
```

---

While this "fixed" my issue, the question remains: Why does an explicit printing as a two-character hex value print 8 characters instead of the two that are specified?

Comment: Could it be the variadic-goodness that make up the printf macro?   Perhaps, but I also tried it using "cout" in C++ and it did the same thing... though I'm not really sure what that might imply.

Comment: it is because of binary representation of negative numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: @guidotex exactly as @[Raxvan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378633/c-printing-negative-int-values-as-hex-produces-too-many-characters#comment48846741_30378633) said, you can try using `unsigned char` instead, and it will work as you expect.

Comment: @Raxvan - good background info! thanks for the link.

Comment: @iharob - I gave this a try and mentioned it in the original question posting.  It works - looking for more of the "why".  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Note: " "int8_t" may or may not be only 1 byte" - I am confident that if a system supports `int8_t`, it is optional, it must be 1 `char` (byte) in _size_.

Comment: @chux - good to know.  For a shot at great fame and glory (i.e. more reputation :), can you reference that anywhere?    I was under the impression that the standard specifies only the types, but doesn't guarantee how the compiler might implement them.

Comment: @guidotex The spec "c11 der 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types" does detail exact width types like `int8_t` as being 2's complement and no padding: exactly 8-bits "Thus, `int8_t` denotes such a signed
integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits." - no compiler wiggle room there except endian and alignment requirements for wider exact types.  `unsigned char` is not allowed to have padding & `char` must be smallest sized type & at least 8-bits: Ergo `char` is 8-bit.

Comment: @guidotex ...  "When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1" §6.5.3.4 4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `int8_t` will go through the usual integer promotions as a parameter to a variadic function like `printf()`.  This typically means the `int8_t` is converted to `int`.

Yet `"%X"` is meant for `unsigned` arguments.  So covert to some unsigned type first and use a matching format specifier:

For `uint8_t`, use `PRIX8`.  With exact width types, include `<inttypes.h>` for the matching specifiers.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
printf(" int negative var is <%02" PRIX8 ">\n", iNegVar);`
```

With `int8_t iNegVar = -1;`, convert to some unsigned type before printing in hex

```
printf(" int negative var is <%02" PRIX8 ">\n", (uint8_t) iNegVar);`
```

Comment: I hadn't thought to use the exact width type macros with a cast.  Was not aware that %X was intended for unsigned arguments - just thought that it took whatever the bit value was of the argument.  Thanks!

Comment: @guidotex True that _most_ systems will nicely work with `"%x"` and some signed integer is passed - yet it is UB per spec.

Answer (score 6):

It's because `%x` has default size of int.
If you want char, use `%hhx`
Or better, you have the [macros in `<cinttypes>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/), like `PRIx8`

Comment: This works and starts my thinking in the right direction. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `char` value to sprintf() or any other variadic C function it is promoted to `int` value -1 in this case. Now you print it as `unsigned int` by "%X" spec, so you get long number with FF. `unsigned char` on another side promoted to `unsigned int` so you get 0xFF integer value which is printed as 2 symbols.

Note: the fact that you specify %X - unsigned int in `printf()` formatting only affects how printf function treats the value passed to it. Char -> int promotion happens before `printf()` called and format specifier does not have effect, only type of the value you are passing.

Comment: It should be made clear that using `%X` on `-1` causes undefined behaviour